# Get result set from a single column table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

I have a table country with single column that has the below values

```
India
Pakistan
Australia
Srilanka
```

My result should be like this

```
India vs Pakistan 
India vs Australia
India vs Srilanka
Pakistan vs Srilanka
Pakistan vs Australia
Australia vs Srilanka
```

How do we achieve this with self join?

Tried with self join but unable to know how to retrieve first value and second value from column

Answer (score 2):

Use the self join with a condition so that a country cannot play against itself:

```
CREATE TABLE counties (
    name varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO counties (name)
VALUES ('India'), ('Pakistan'), ('Australia'), ('Srilanka');

SELECT
     CONCAT(c1.name, ' vs ', c2.name) AS matchup
FROM counties c1
JOIN counties c2 ON c1.name < c2.name
ORDER BY
    matchup;
```

| matchup |
| --- |
| Australia vs India |
| Australia vs Pakistan |
| Australia vs Srilanka |
| India vs Pakistan |
| India vs Srilanka |
| Pakistan vs Srilanka |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lW_IevzP)

More combinations can be achieved with `<>` in the condition:

```
SELECT
     CONCAT(c1.name, ' vs ', c2.name) AS matchup
FROM counties c1
JOIN counties c2 ON c1.name <> c2.name
ORDER BY
    matchup;
```

| matchup |
| --- |
| Australia vs India |
| Australia vs Pakistan |
| Australia vs Srilanka |
| India vs Australia |
| India vs Pakistan |
| India vs Srilanka |
| Pakistan vs Australia |
| Pakistan vs India |
| Pakistan vs Srilanka |
| Srilanka vs Australia |
| Srilanka vs India |
| Srilanka vs Pakistan |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aoUlQ52X)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`, and `WHERE c1.name < c2.name`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c1.name, ' vs ', c2.name) AS Combination
FROM counties c1
CROSS JOIN counties c2
WHERE c1.name < c2.name
ORDER BY Combination
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iSykPjRl)